# Is it possible to pass a celery task as parameter in a dango view?

Tags: python, django, view, celery, task

I would like to know if it is possible to pass a celery task as a parameter in a django (function based) view?

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but when I try to do it I get an error like this:

```
No connection adapters were found for '<@task: my_module.tasks.my_task....
```

The code loooks like this:

```
def base_myview(request, task, arg1, arg2):
    do stuff ...
    taks.apply_async([arg1, arg2])
    do more stuff
    return some_response
```

```
def view1(request, view1_task, arg1, arg2):
    return base_myview(request, view1_task, arg1, arg2)

def view2(request, view2_task, another_arg1, another_arg2):
    return base_myview(request, view2_task, another_arg1, another_arg2)
# etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (surely) this is not te best solution, but:

```
TASK_DICT = {
    'taks1': view_task1,
    'task2': view_task2,
}

def base_myview(request, task_name: str, arg1, arg2):
    do stuff ....
    TASK_DICT[task_name].apply_async([arg1, arg2])
    do more stuff 
    return some_response

def view1(request, arg1, arg2, task_name='task1'):
    return base_myview(request, task_name, arg1, arg2)

def view2(request, arg1, arg2, task_name='task2'):
    return base_myview(request, task_name, arg1, arg2)
```